# how to show the swaggerUI request examples from baseRequestDto?

Tags: c#, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have a WebAPI Project with the Swashbuckle for its documentation. I have another project to put my abstractions and base class there and I implemented one base class to contain some essential properties that should be included in all requests. So, I want to show some example data in swagger UI using `<summary>` and `<example>` documentation tags. but, looks like these tags are only working on the derived classes and the swagger UI does not show the example data from the base.

Is there any way to include inherited docs and examples in Swagger?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I am using this line of code to embed my XML documentation in my Swagger UI:

```
var xmlFilename = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFilename));
```

So, the documentation of my abstraction project is not included there and I add that by this code.

```
 var files = Directory.GetFiles(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
 foreach (var file in files)
 {
     options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, file));
 }
```

So it seems we should embed all dependencies documentation inside the hosted service.